# Activity uses much memory, how to reduce it?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have an activity that uses about 70 MB of memory, and even when I close that activity by calling `finish()`, the memory does not free up. When I start it again, it adds 70 MB more memory usage. It uses a database but I don't think that the database is the problem because I use the database in another activity and it uses only 14 MB of memory. Here's the code of the class that leaks memory:

```
package ir.noideaw.aufbau;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.GradientDrawable;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import ir.noideaw.aufbau.Adapter.UnitAdapter;
import ir.noideaw.aufbau.DatabaseHandler.DatabaseAccess;
import ir.noideaw.aufbau.Model.Unit;


public class ElementInfo extends AppCompatActivity {
    private ImageView elementPic;
    private CollapsingToolbarLayout ct;
    private AppBarLayout appBarLayout;
    private int currentApiVersion;
    private ArrayList<Unit> ovUnitsData;
    private List<String> properties;
    private ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.element_details);
        initialize();
        Bundle data = getIntent().getExtras();
        final String sy = data.getString("elementSymbol");
        DatabaseAccess database = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
        database.open();
        properties = database.setProperties(sy);
        database.close();
        int atomicNumber = Integer.valueOf(database.getAtomicNumber());
        int id = getResources().getIdentifier("element_" + atomicNumber, "drawable", getPackageName());
        if (id != 0) {
            elementPic.setImageResource(id);
        } else {
            elementPic.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(database.getColor()));
        }
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow = true;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {
                    ct.setTitle(sy);
                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                    ct.setTitle(" ");//careful there should be a space between double quote otherwise it wont work
                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });
        setUnitsData();
        UnitAdapter adapter = new UnitAdapter(this, ovUnitsData);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        listView.setMinimumHeight(listView.getChildCount()*40);
        currentApiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
        final int flags = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY;
        if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
            final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
            decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                    if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                        decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(listView);
        setListViewDevider(listView);
        listView.setDividerHeight(1);
        System.gc();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        if (currentApiVersion >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT && hasFocus) {
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Runtime.getRuntime().gc();
    }

    private void initialize() {
        elementPic = findViewById(R.id.backdrop);
        ct = findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appbar);
        listView = findViewById(R.id.ov_list_view);
        ovUnitsData = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static void setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(ListView listView) {
        ListAdapter listAdapter = listView.getAdapter();
        if (listAdapter == null) {
            // pre-condition
            return;
        }
        int totalHeight = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < listAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
            View listItem = listAdapter.getView(i, null, listView);
            listItem.measure(0, 0);
            totalHeight += listItem.getMeasuredHeight();
        }
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = listView.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = totalHeight + (listView.getDividerHeight() * (listAdapter.getCount() - 1));
        listView.setLayoutParams(params);
        listView.requestLayout();
    }

    public void setListViewDevider(ListView listView){
        listView.setDivider(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#d4d2d1")));
    }

    private void setUnitsData() {
        String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.ov);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
            ovUnitsData.add(new Unit(properties.get(i), array[i]));
        }
    }
}
```

Visiting Android Profiler, it shows about 60 MB of memory is used by Java. Also the layout files:
elements_details.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="320dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:collapsedTitleGravity="top"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:titleEnabled="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/backdrop"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/element_1"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="top"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                android:paddingBottom="30dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/element_symbol"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                        android:textSize="40dp" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/element_symbol"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/element_name"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/element_molar_mass"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                            android:textSize="15dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/nested_scroll_view" />
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

nested_scroll_view.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <RelativeLayout style="@style/TitleRelativeLayout">

            <RelativeLayout style="@style/TitleRelativeLayoutInRelativeLayout">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/atom_image"
                    style="@style/TitleImageView"
                    android:src="@drawable/atom" />

                <TextView
                    style="@style/TitleTextView"
                    android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/atom_image"
                    android:text="@string/overview" />
            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <include layout="@layout/overview"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

In addition, I don't think it is related to `ListView` because when I removed it, I didn't face any difference.
How can I reduce memory usage?
My target is 40 MB.
**UPDATE:**
Android Profiler-Memory:
[image: Android Profiler-Memory]

Heap dump:
[image: Heap dump]

Comment: If you don't use database and don't set properties, how is it then?

Comment: does your activity and list view has images with large size ?

Comment: Have you checked if this activity has ciclic references? If there are, even the activity is closed, the memory is used because another object has a reference to that activity. Try to free all variables of your activity in `onDestroy()`

Comment: @MHSFisher it has images but the largest size is 100 KB

Comment: @MarcEstrada I tried setting all variables equal to null but didn't work.

Comment: @JackJohnson 100k for each image in list ??!!! really? don't do this ! in your list, each image should be at most 1 KB or less. try to reduce your image size and resolution and be sure your memory would be released.

Comment: @MHSFisher Not in list. The activity has only one image with size of 100k. That is in collapsing toolbar.

Comment: @JackJohnson i mean the images that are in each item of list. if them size is large, try to reduce them. most of the time hanging or memory usage like your problem is because of processing on loading images.

Comment: @MHSFisher Can you understand the problem from that images? :|

Answer (score 0):

If each time you start `Activity` memory consumption grows and this memory is not released when the activity is finished, then you probably have memory leak.

Looking at your code I would check two things:

Don't pass `Activity` reference here:

```
DatabaseAccess database = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(this);
```

Do this in `onStart()` and then remove the listener in `onStop()`:

```
final View decorView = getWindow().getDecorView();
decorView.setOnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener(new View.OnSystemUiVisibilityChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSystemUiVisibilityChange(int visibility) {
                if ((visibility & View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN) == 0) {
                    decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(flags);
                }
            }
        });
```